# Logging URLs in Apache Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, logging, url

I was wondering if there is some configuration, built-in functionality in Tomcat that logs the URLs people are using to reach your website?

for example:

- `http://www.mypage.com/1.htm`
- `http://www.mypage.com/2.htm`
- `http://www.mypage.com/3.htm`

etc etc

Can we enable some tomcat setting that would log which pages are being accessed the most?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to set up access logs. Here's a link that guides you through the process for [Tomcat 6 Access Logging (old link)](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://blog.techstacks.com/2008/08/tomcat-6-access-logging.html) / 
[Tomcat 6 Access Logging (new link)](http://blog.techstacks.com/2008/08/tomcat-6-access-logging.html)